# Permutation combination questions?

Tags: permutations, combinations

An access pad has 7 buttons. An access code is a sequence of 2, 3, 4 buttons. How many access codes are possible if:
buttons may be repeated 
buttons may not be repeated

I need help getting this started. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer the following question:

How many access codes exist with $n$ buttons?

Note that each button has $7$ options. Hence, the number of access codes with $n$ buttons is $7 \times 7 \times \cdots \times 7 = 7^n$.

I trust you can complete the rest.